# Difference between static methods and nonstatic methods in object

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I am currently learning to program in the language C# with the german book "Schrödinger Programmiert C#" and at the page 156 there is a code example. The problem is: I don't understand why I use a static in the second method but not in the first one.

**Person class**

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float WalkedKm
    {
        get
        { 
            return this.Footsteps * 0.75f / 1000.0f;
        }
    }
    public float Weight { get; set; }
    public int Footsteps { get; private set; }

    public void Walk (int Footsteps)
    {
        if (Footsteps > -1)
            this.Footsteps += Footsteps;
    }

    public static float AverageWalkedKm(Person[] persons)
    {
        int amount = persons.Length;
        float walkSum = 0;
        foreach (Person p in persons)
            walkSum += p.WalkedKm;
        return walkSum / (float)amount;
    }
}
```

**In the Main Method**

```
Person p1 = new Person();
Person p2 = new Person();
p1.Name = "Schrödinger";
p2.Name = "Schrödingers Girlfriend";
p1.Walk(1500);
p2.Walk(1500);
p2.Walk(2100);
Person[] person = new Person[] { p1, p2 };
Console.WriteLine("Schrödingers steps: {0}. km {1}", p1.Footsteps, p1.WalkedKm);
Console.WriteLine("Her steps: {0}. km {1}", p2.Footsteps, p2.WalkedKm);
float average = Person.AverageWalkedKm(person);
Console.WriteLine("Average: {0}km", average);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Please help me to understand the difference!

Comment: WalkedKm is not declared as static because it needs to access the state (this.Footsteps) of the instance of the class its called across. AverageWalkedKm can be static as it does not use any state stored within the class.  A Static is considered preferable because you don't need to create an instance of the class it is attached to, or clutter it up with methods that are only loosely coupled with its internal logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`float AverageWalkedKm(Person[] persons)` can be static because it does not attempt to access any *instance* members (fields, properties, or methods) of the class.

`void Walk (int Footsteps)` cannot be static because it does access *instance* members of the class.  (Namely, the `Footsteps` property.)

Note: *instance* members = non-static members.

**EDIT**

So, you object that in the `AverageWalkedKm()` the `Person[] persons` parameter is of datatype `Person`, so it seems to you that it is accessing instance members.

Well, yes, it is accessing instance members, but not ***of its own instance***. It is given the instances that it works with.  So, this method could belong to an entirely different class, and it would still work, unchanged, because it is given instances of `Person` to invoke.  When we say that an instance method is capable of accessing instance members we mean ***of its own instance***, as in `this.member`, or even without `this.`, as it is optional.

Comment: You should correct your sentence with: _"any member fields, properties, or methods of the class THAT IS NOT STATIC"_, or _"THAT DOESN'T BELONG TO A PARTICULAR INSTANCE"_, or something similar.

Comment: Okay. But in the AverageWalkedKm method parameters **Person[] persons** there is a array with the datatyp "Person", isn't that attempting to acces any instance members?

Comment: @RafaelFarcher okay, I see where your confusion lies.  I amended my answer.

Comment: **Main method**  `p1.MoveRight(); //nonstatic
int playerLife = Player.HowMuchLifeDoIHave(p1); //static`             
 **class Player** public void MoveRight() {
            //Left
            this.X += 4;
        }                                                                                                                   
       public static int HowMuchLifeDoIHave(Player p1)
        {
            return p1.Life;
        } Is that logically correct?

Comment: Yes, although I do not like the naming you have chosen.  If it is static, then   it has no notion of "self", so I would not use the word "I" in the name.  Plus, it would be a nicer design to have the `Player` instance tell you how much life it has, so `HowMuchLifeDoIHave()` would be suitable as an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using the Footsteps variable, which is not static

Answer (score 0):

You use static methods when you don't need (or want) to require an object-instance of the class. In your example, you can call the Person.AverageWalkedKm method whether or not you've created an object-instance of the Person class. However, because the Walk method refers to an instance variable (Footsteps), it cannot be static: You must first create an instance of the Person class (p1 and p2 in your example) and then use those instances in order to call the Walk method.